# Running Protractor In Parallel Across Multiple Browsers

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to run a protractor test in parallel across three browsers namely internet explorer, firefox & chrome. I will probably add more browsers as time goes on for instance edge.

In any case I am able to run the tests one instance at a time using this configuration

```
seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar';
seleniumArgs: '-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver_2.22.exe'
seleniumArgs: '-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./node_modules/protractor/selenium/geckodriver_v0.9.0.exe'
seleniumArgs: '-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=./node_modules/protractor/selenium/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.1.exe'

// Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
capabilities:
{

    browserName: 'firefox',

    ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true,

    'pageLoadStrategy': 'eager',

    'marionette': 'true',

 },
```

i.e. I'd comment in the seleniumArg I require depending on which browser I'm testing against and I'd change browserName within capabilities & comment marionette if I'm not using firefox. I have a neat way of doing this via environment variables but this gives an idea of how i'm approaching this.

Now I want to do this is in parallel so now I have another config file like so

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

multiCapabilities:
[
    {

        browserName: 'firefox',

        pageLoadingStrategy: 'eager',

        ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true,

        marionette: true,

    },
    {

        browserName: 'chrome',

        pageLoadingStrategy: 'eager',

        ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true

    },
    {

        browserName: 'internet explorer',

        IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings: true,

        ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true

    }

],
```

but anytime I run this configuration all browsers instances throw an error saying that they can't find the driver executable

```
 [internet explorer #21] WebDriverError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information
 [firefox #01] WebDriverError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;
 [chrome #11] WebDriverError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information,
```

By the way prior to running the configuration file I execute webdriver-manager start

So I suppose the question is how does one make the driver path known within the multiCapabilities object? Or is this the suggested way to run parallel tests with protractor namely connect to a certain selenium address? Many thanks in advance as to any information anyone provides.

My config.json looks like this btw if it makes any difference

```
{
"webdriverVersions":
  {
   "selenium": "2.53.1",
   "chromedriver": "2.22",
   "iedriver": "2.53.1"
   }
 }
```

Comment: I personally start all of this externally using node and hub config files that handle the path for the driver files and opening selenium server using Java but try formatting your selenium args like this and including them all in the same array seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=<path to IEDriverServer.exe>']

Comment: I use the same process as @sonhu